# WPF TextBox.Text with MultiBinding

Tags: wpf, textbox, triggers, controltemplate, multitrigger

I've got Custom Control with a TextBox in the default Template.
The Custom Control has these 2 dependency properties (among others):

SelectedValue, NullText (text to appear in the TextBox when nothing is selected and the value is provided)

I'd like to **set the TextBox.Text with the NullText** value when the `SelectedValue` null is and the `NullText` not null is.

```
<TextBox.Text>                                              
 <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
   <Binding RelativeSource="TemplatedParent" Path="SelectedValue"/>
   <Binding RelativeSource="TemplatedParent" Path="NullText"/>
 </MultiBinding>                                              
</TextBox.Text>
```

I've got a IMultiValueConverter:

```
public class MyConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{}
```

With this XAML definition I got 'type does not have a public TypeConverter class' Exception

How would you solve it, please?

Comment: sorry, didn't realize you actually were posting an answer, I thought you where just updating the question (downvote removed)

Comment: OK :) What should I do now? Because the question is still open

Comment: Rather than posting your solution as an Edit, post your solution as an answer, and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I found the **SOLUTION** by myself:
The problem was with the RelativeSource.
This is how it should look like:

```
<TextBox.Text>                                              
 <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
   <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="SelectedValue"/>
   <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}" Path="NullText"/>
 </MultiBinding>                                              
</TextBox.Text>
```