# How to multi-bind ProgressBar's value in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

There is a concept of `Multibinding` in `WPF`, which is really useful if we want to bind some UI Control that depends on multiple values, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2185202/1823643) one.

I am trying to do the same with `ProgressBar`, like I am using `ProgressBar` to display how much storage is used by the users and it depends on two properties.

1. UsedStorage
2. TotalStorage

After searching, i could not find a way to bind `Value` property of `ProgressBar` with multiple properties and custom convertor.

Something like (Just a concept)

```
<ProgressBar Width="172" Height="16" >
    <ProgressBar.Value>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource myConverter}">
            <Binding  Path="UsedStorage" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
            <Binding  Path="TotalStorage"  RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </ProgressBar.Value>
</ProgressBar>
```

But problem is there is nothing like `MultiBinding` under `ProgressBar.Value`. So the question is,

Is there a way to `MultiBind` `ProgressBar` `Value`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though the Visual Studio intellisense might not show that, it is perfectly valid.

However, Using `RelativeSource TemplatedParent` only works inside a `ControlTemplate`. It is unclear to me where are you trying to get your values from.